# How to not allow localhost point to my alias in WAMP?

Tags: php, wamp

My System hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       mysite.com
```

VirtualHost in my apache conf.httpd:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www/some_folder_name/public"
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

So I want to access my site folder via that alias, but the problem is, if I make `mysite.com` point to `127.0.0.1` which then is handled by apache, then the `localhost` is pointing to this site folder too, how can I avoid this, leaving localhost pointing to the default WAMP page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define listen ports.

```
Listen 80
Listen 8000
<VirtualHost *:80>
     #config for 80
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8000>
     #config for 8000
</VirtualHost>
```

In host file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1:8000       mysite.com
```

Comment: yes that worked, but now I have to write mysite.com:8000, because if I write it in the system hosts file like this 127.0.0.1:8000 mysite.com it isn't working at all..looks like there are no way put the port number there..

Comment: yeep that's true. read this article: http://serverfault.com/questions/54357/can-i-specify-a-port-in-an-entry-in-my-etc-hosts-on-os-x